# How can I limit the div (autocomplete-item) created by JS for autocomplete search?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, dom-events

I have created a autocomplete search box using the code in the link: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp)

I am using a list of 3000 cities (JSON file). When performing the search, the search list is too long. How can I limit the size of the divs being created by JS or even set a fixed height for the division containing that list and make it scrollable?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) to the outer div and handle the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```css
.autocomplete-items {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```